# TypeScript: Why does readonly work so differently with arrays?

Tags: typescript, readonly

Here is a simple example of a class in which I declared two arrays in different ways:

1. readonly arr: string[];
2. arr2: ReadonlyArray<string>;

```
class ReadonlyArrsClass {
  readonly arr: string[] = ['1', '2'];
  arr2: ReadonlyArray<string> = ['1', '2'];

  addToArr(): void {
    this.arr.push('333'); // okay.
  }

  addToArr2(): void {
    this.arr2.push('444'); // error!
  }

  changeArrData(): void {
    this.arr = ['555']; // error!
  }
  changeArr2Data(): void {
    this.arr2 = ['666']; // okay.
  }

   logToConsole(): void {
    console.log(this.arr);
    console.log(this.arr2);
  }

  constructor(){
    this.addToArr();
    this.addToArr2();
    this.logToConsole();
    this.changeArrData();
    this.changeArr2Data();
    this.logToConsole();
  }
}

new ReadonlyArrsClass;
```

---

Why in case 1. I can still add elements to the end of the `arr` using push()?

But in case 2. I can’t. (which seems more logical). I'm getting the error Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly string[]'.

---

Why in case 2. I can reassign the reference of the `arr2`?

But in case 1. I get an error - Cannot assign to 'arr' because it is a read-only property.

---

Can someone explain why this works this way and what is preferable to use ?

Or don't use it at all

Comment: `readonly arr` just means you can't do `this.arr = <something else>` it doesn't limit how  you use the instance object itself. If you truly want an immutable array that is also not reassignable you need `readonly arr: ReadonlyArray<string> = [ '1', '2' ]`

Comment: • "what is preferable to use" is an opinion question unless you have a specific use case in mind. Can you [edit] to either remove that part or make it clear what the goal is, so that it can be answered objectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I understood the following: It is necessary to separate

- `readonly arr`
- `string[]`
- `ReadonlyArray<string>`

and then it will become clear what the difference is.

When you use `readonly arr`, then we are talking about an object and if you initialize it, you cannot change it (including its type). That is, you cannot reassign a new array, but you can push into an old one.

When you use `string[]` or `ReadonlyArray<string>`, then we are talking only about the type and only the type is responsible for the behavior - in this case, if **arr does not have `readonly`**, then you can create and assign new objects.

In terms of use, you need to understand what is needed for the task:

1. `readonly arr: ReadonlyArray<string>` - is essentially a constant that you defined and you cannot change in any way, neither assign a new object (change the reference), nor push it.
2. `arr: ReadonlyArray<string>` - you can assign a new array, but you cannot push.
3. `readonly arr: string[]` - you can push, but you cannot assign new array.

Then, based on the task, you choose what to use:

- If you define a collection that needs to be supplemented, choose option 3.
- If you want to reassign - option 2.
- If neither this nor that - option 1.